# How can two children from one class interact with each other?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two players created from the Player class, they have their own army with attack 10 and defense 5.

When I enter `player1.attack ()` the first player attacks the second player's army, but I just don't understand how two children from one class can interact with each other.

Please give me some examples or tell where I can read about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help:

```js
class Player {
  constructor(d, a) {
    this.defense = d;
    this.attack = a;
  }

  static attack(attacker, defender) {
    defender.defense -= attacker.attack;
  }
}

var p1 = new Player(10, 5);
var p2 = new Player(100, 20);

Player.attack(p1, p2);
console.log(p1);
console.log(p2);
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you use a class method for this? Especially since JavaScript has functions?

Answer (score 0):

One child must have a *reference* to another:

```
let p1 = new Player();
let p2 = new Player();

p1.attack(p2);
```

In this case I've explicitly passed the reference to p2 as an argument to the `attack` method, which would look something like this:

```
class Player {
  constructor () {
    this.health = 50;
    this.attack = 10;
    this.defense = 5;
  }

  takeHit (attackRating) {
    let damage = attackRating - this.defense;
    if (damage > 0) {
      this.health -= damage;
        if (this.health < 1) {
        this.die();
      }
    }
  }

  attack (enemy) {
    // we'll assume we were passed a valid player, you can
    // check if you wish.
    enemy.takeHit(this.attack);
  }
}
```

Implementation of the `die` method left as an exercise to the reader.